Are voids in the Universe more ideal places for Special Relativity and Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation?
If voids are areas with weaker gravitational forces, then wouldn't they be ideal places for the postulates of Special Relativity and the propositions of Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation? I'm assuming that in voids, light moves close to its maximum speed and is in vacuo, and that also in voids there are weaker gravitational forces which make NLUG inverse-square law approximations more accurate for small distances. The key idea is place; are voids ideal places in our Universe for each of these physics paradigms?

The matter of how Newtonian gravity compares to relativistic gravity is clear, but it is not clear what more accurate theory you intend special relativity to be compared to.

You could argue that intergalactic space is too flat and too empty to tell us anything useful, and that the best way to advance our knowledge is to study how light behaves in extreme scenarios such as close to a black hole or in the very early universe.

Newtonian theory works very accurately on everyday Earth, no need to wander off looking for more exotic locations for that.
